# tcpdump missing most packets when -w is used

Tags: linux, networking, wireshark, tcpdump

When I use `$ sudo tcpdump -i ens160` I can see a lot of noise in my VM. Like 150 packages in a few seconds. Mostly on port `64651`. I don't know what that noise is so I am trying to figure it out.

So I use `$ sudo tcpdump -i ens160 -w noise.pcap`. Now I get maybe 10 packets in 30 seconds, none of them are for port 64651, just ARP protocol.

I tried
`$ sudo tcpdump -i ens160 -w noise.pcap -U`
`$ sudo tcpdump -i ens160 -B 10000 -w noise.pcap -U`
`$ sudo tcpdump -i ens160 -B 10000 -w noise.pcap -U`
`$ sudo tcpdump -i ens160 -w noise.pcap port 64651`

No success.
Even if I do `$ sudo tcpdump -i ens160 >> noise.txt`, the data that I see on the screen isn't saved to the file.

The result of the capture is always `0 packets dropped`

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What do the "noise" messages actually look like?

Comment: `04:42:45.148566 IP 192.168.1.1.2222 > 10.70.231.60.64651: Flags [P.], seq 22424:22636, ack 1, win 314, options [nop,nop,TS val 4137914904 ecr 1100706144], length 212`

Comment: Are you SSH-ing to the VM? Then you need to get packets to see information about packets, so it escalates. Unless you redirect the output.

Comment: I am SSHing. I just don't understand why I can see all of that noise without the -w, but I don't see them with -w in a file, once I read the , pcap file.

Comment: Because those are your _SSH packets._ The tcpdump output being printed to your screen is literally what _causes_ those packets in the first place.

Comment: If you ask a friend to keep reporting to you every flying bird they see, without substantial delay, via pigeon post, then the friend will need to send pigeons to report previous pigeons. If you ask him to write a report instead and put it in a drawer, he won't see as many pigeons because he won't be sending them.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot. Well thanks guys. I think I'll delete this post :) I am debuging another thing with tcpreplay and though this would have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason tcpdump doesn't capture anything when redirected to a file is because the packets in question are the same SSH packets that *show tcpdump's output*. The first packet might be caused by the TCP ACK after your 'Enter' keypress; tcpdump printing the first packet over SSH causes the second packet; the second packet being printed causes the 3rd, and so on. Every captured packet generates a new packet again.

To avoid this during an interactive capture, filter out the SSH packets, e.g. `not tcp port 2222`. If you want a more precise filter, you could use $SSH_CONNECTION to find your local port (e.g. if you still want to see *other* SSH packets, just not your own):

```
read -r rhost rport lhost lport <<< "$SSH_CONNECTION"
tcpdump -i ens160 "not (host $rhost and host $lhost and tcp port $rport and tcp port $lport)"
```

Wireshark on Windows used to detect when it's being run via Remote Desktop and automatically select the filter `not port 3389` to avoid this situation.